# Why We use WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
package com.ge.hc.gsit.sbom.configuration;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.xy.gsit.sbom.controller","com.abc.xy.gsit.sbom.exception"})
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter{
}
```

Hi,

I want to know how WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter class is working.

If any documents is present please let me know, It will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Comment in the `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` states that:

> // Defined as a nested config to ensure WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is not read when not
>
> // on the classpath

`WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` class extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and provides default implementation of `WebMvcConfigurer` interfaces methods that are callbacks to customize the Java-based configuration for Spring MVC enabled via `@EnableWebMvc`.

So, if you want to changes some behavior you should extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

More details about `EnableAutoConfiguration` and Spring Boot in general: [Understanding Spring Boot](https://geowarin.github.io/understanding-spring-boot.html)